# Activating a subform in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

I have an MS Access main Dashboard form that contains a number of subforms. The tables and records live in an online database and I use ODBC to connect to the tables. Rather than all subforms being displayed when the dashboard loads I'd prefer them to be opened on demand from the dashboard - this would speed up loading of the dashboard form. The subforms have some complex queries behind them.
Is there any way of leaving the subforms dormant when the dashboard form first opens (so it opens nice and quick) and then opening the subforms on demand using a button click, i.e. only pull down the data for the subforms via ODBC when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a subform object, then set it programatically using `Me.Child0.SourceObject = "MySubForm"`

Comment: Link Child and Link Master fields can also be set at run time. I have found that it is usually best to set the link master fields to controls when using a single subform control for multiple forms.